# Add options to dropdown via JQuery AJAX request (as json Object)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I currently try to get into JQuery and, to be more specific, into AJAX requests.

**Code:**
Javascript:

```
success: function(json) {
        console.log(json);
        var $el = $("#system");
        $el.empty(); // remove old options
        $el.append($("<option></option>")
            .attr("value", '').text('Please Select'));

        // for each set of data, add a new option
        $.each(json, function(value, key) {
            $el.append($("<option></option>")
                .attr("value", value).text(key));
        });

},
```

HTML:

```
<form id="filter">
    <label for="datepicker">
        Date: <input id="datepicker" onchange="updateSystems()" type="text" />
    </label>
    &nbsp;
    <label>from:
        <select id="timespan-from"  name="timespan-from" onchange="updateSystems()" size="1">
            <option value="0">0 Uhr</option>
            ...
            <option value="23">23 Uhr</option>
        </select>
    </label>
    &nbsp;
    <label>to:
        <select id="timespan-to" name="timespan-to" onchange="updateSystems()" size="1">
            <option value="0">23 Uhr</option>
            ...
            <option value="0">0 Uhr</option>
        </select>
    </label>
    &nbsp;
    <label>in System:
        <select id="system" name="system" size="1">
            <!-- this should be updated -->
            <option>Amarr</option>
            <option>JEIV-E</option>
            <option>Jita</option>
            <option>Litom</option>
            <option>Penis</option>
        </select>
    </label>
</form>
```

This function is triggered whenever I change a field in my document, 
and should update the elements of a html dropdown.

The AJAX request works, but the dropdown-update does not work as intended. I try to add some `<option>` fields to the `<select>` dropdown with the id `id=system`.

However, the result dropdown always looks like this:

- Please Select
- [object Object]

What needs to be changed so my functions adds my json data to my dropdown menu?

Example JSON return from my php script:

```
[
    {
        "solarSystemID": "30001171",
        "solarSystemName": "F4R2-Q"
    },
    {
        "solarSystemID": "30001182",
        "solarSystemName": "MB-NKE"
    },
    {
        "solarSystemID": "30004299",
        "solarSystemName": "Sakht"
    },
    {
        "solarSystemID": "30004738",
        "solarSystemName": "1-SMEB"
    }
]
```

`solarSystemID` should become the value of the `<option>`,
`solarSystemName` should be the text.

Thanks in advance for any help, I guess I just need a little push in the right direction for it to finally work as intended.

Comment: When you debug, what are the values of `key` and `value` that you're using to build the `option` element(s)?  It would appear that one of them is an object, not a literal value.

Comment: Please show all relevant code in the question itself. We shouldn't have to go off site to review your issue. Questions should be self contained

Comment: value would be 0..1..2..3 ... key would be an Object every time ... coerced to a string an object becomes `[object Object]` - by the way, jQuery.each callback arguments are key, value, not value, key - you're possibly thinking of Array#forEach

Comment: @charlietfl I will try to update my anwser so the JS code is actually in the post. You are totally right, the github-content will change and then the question becomes unclear. Will fix it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the map method for mapping Solar object to option element.

```
$('#system').append(json.map(function(sObj){
    return '<option id="'+sObj.solarSystemID+'">'+ sObj.solarSystemName +'</option>'
}));
```

Comment: I like this because it does a single append rather than an append for each item! which makes browsers happy :p

Comment: This works like a charm, thanks! However, there is a closing `)` missing at the end!

Comment: fixed it , glad I could help :)